# c strncpy null terminated or not

Tags: c, strncpy

I am reading [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) document, it says:

> ```
> char *strncpy(char *destination, const char *source, size_t num);
> ```
>
> Copy characters from string
>    Copies the first `num` characters of `source` to `destination`. If the end of the `source` C string (which is signaled by a null-character) is found before `num` characters have been copied, `destination` is padded with zeros until a total of `num` characters have been written to it.
>
> No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than `num`. Thus, in this case, `destination` shall not be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would overflow).
>
> `destination` and `source` shall not overlap (see `memmove` for a safer alternative when overlapping).

But I am confused by this statement:

> in this case, destination shall not be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would overflow)

Since if `num > strlen(source)`, it will pad with `'\0'` at the end, `'\0'` is actually a null (terminating) character in a string, why it shall not be considered a null-terminated C string?

I have written below code to verify:

```
  char from[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
  char to[1024];
  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
      to[i] = 'e';
  }
  strncpy(to, from, 1024);
  printf("from %s\n", from);
```

It works fine with below output:

```
from hello
to hello
```

Comment: `strncpy`: just don't use it.

Comment: The lack of a `'\0'`is where `strlen(source) > num`, so I think you just have a simple misunderstanding - try `strncpy(to, from, 2);` instead.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to replace strncpy in 2023, you std::string::copy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's talking about the case when `strlen(source)` > `num`.  It will only copy `num` chars, none of which is a NUL and it will not add a NUL.

Comment: ...and to make sure you *do* get a NUL terminator, use `strlcpy` instead of `strncpy`.

Answer (score 6):

`strncpy(dst, src, len)` only adds a null terminator to `dst` if there is a null terminator in `src` within the first `len` bytes. Your code might seem to work, because there might or might not be a null character after the array `to[]`. A better test is:

```
char source[] = "source";
char dest[] = "destination";
strncpy(dest, source, 6);
printf("%s\n", dest);
```

The result should be:

```
sourceation
```

If you write `strncpy(dest, source, 7)` instead, then the output is just the word `source`.

Answer (score 3):

The semantics of `strncpy()`, even when precisely explained as they are in the C++ reference above, are widely misunderstood. The behavior of this function is counterintuitive and error prone.

To avoid problems when using it or further down the development process, when the maintainer will misread the code and add more subtile bugs, there is a simple solution: **NEVER EVER USE THIS FUNCTION**.

You can read further details about this in [this article by Bruce Dawson](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/).

To answer your question: if the source string is longer than the size passed as a third argument (usually corresponding to the size of the destination buffer), the function will copy size characters to the destination and no null byte will be present among these.  Calling `strlen(destination);` will then invoke undefined behavior because it will attempt to read beyond the end of the array until it finds a null terminator.  This specific behavior is what makes `strncpy` so error prone.

Comment: @EvilTeach: I updated the answer. It is important to deter newbies from using this error prone function.  I have seen so many instances of misuse, even by experienced programmers... It acts as a universal bug attractor.

Comment: This is the best answer now.  It's a shame the NEVER USE THIS FUNCTION can't be blinking between red and black.

Comment: i would add strtok, atoi, atof and the whole scanf family to the list of functions to avoid.

Comment: @EvilTeach: I agree about `strtok` and `scanf`. `atoi` and `atof` do not provide error checking but are much less problematic. `feof()` is pretty high on the list too, `sprintf()` should be replaced with `snprintf()`, `char` should be unsigned by default, 2s complement mandated, as well as 8/16/32/and 64 bit integer types, IEEE floating point... That would make C so much simpler.

Comment: @EvilTeach: `feof()` is almost systematically misused in `while (!feof(fp))`.  `char` signed by default is inconsistent with `getc()` returning the values of the `unsigned char` type plus `EOF`, `strcmp()` comparing strings as arrays of `unsigned char` and functions from `<ctype.h>` invoking undefined behavior for negative `char` values.